# (SQL) How to get file name and size using xp_dirtree?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get all files information like size, date, etc.. in sql server using xp_dirtree. but xp_dirtree only give output files name, is there any ways to get the files info ?

Comment: And WHY do you think that tsql running in a sql server instance with an account that should have limited access to external resources is the appropriate path to your goal? Time to take a few steps back and reconsider your goal and the decisions that led to this problem. The short answer is that there is no built-in functionality to do this. There are, of course, ways to accomplish this but with many assumptions and risks and complications.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952406/get-each-file-size-inside-a-folder-using-sql